# duplicate content in uitableviewcells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm using a PFQueryTableViewController and trying to create a videoCell for each item in Parse.  I only want to play the current active cell.

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell: VideoTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? VideoTableViewCell

  //  cell?.parseObject = object
    if let pfObject = object {
        cell?.nameLabel?.text = pfObject["name"] as? String
        print(pfObject["name"])

    }
    let file: PFFile? = object!.objectForKey("videoFile") as? PFFile
    if self.currentActiveIndex == nil && file != nil {
        self.currentActiveIndex = indexPath.row
        print(file)
        let fileUrl: NSURL? = NSURL(string: file!.url!)
        let player: AVPlayer? = AVPlayer(URL: fileUrl!)
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: &PlayerStatusContext)
        cell?.cellVideoView.setPlayer(player!)
        cell?.cellVideoView.setVideoFillMode(AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill)

    }
    print(objects?.count)


    return cell
}
```

For some reason the video is appearing both in the 1st and 4th cells, every time.  I'm curious as to why. Thanks

Comment: Cells are re-used.  You need to clear the current content before setting the new content.

Comment: @Paulw11 please provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the player is removed when the cell is re-used.

Basically, this means you need an `else` clause for your `if`.  Probably something like -

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell: VideoTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? VideoTableViewCell

  //  cell?.parseObject = object
    if let pfObject = object {
        cell!.nameLabel!.text = pfObject["name"] as! String
        print(pfObject["name"])

    }
    let file: PFFile? = object!.objectForKey("videoFile") as? PFFile
    if self.currentActiveIndex == nil && file != nil {
        self.currentActiveIndex = indexPath.row
        print(file)
        let fileUrl: NSURL? = NSURL(string: file!.url!)
        let player: AVPlayer? = AVPlayer(URL: fileUrl!)
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: &PlayerStatusContext)
        cell?.cellVideoView.setPlayer(player!)
        cell?.cellVideoView.setVideoFillMode(AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill)

    }
    else {
        if let player=cell!.cellVideoView.player {
            player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:"status")
            cell!.cellVideoView.setPlayer(nil)
        }
    }

    print(objects?.count)


    return cell
}
```

Also, you have a lot of `?` where you can use `!`.  For example, `cell` won't be nil (and if it is, that is bad and an exception should be thrown)and the cast to `VideoTableViewCell` or `String` or even `PFFile` shouldn't fail and if it does then something has gone wrong an exception is probably appropriate so that you can debug.

Comment: awesome advice! I'll give this a go

Comment: Hmm when I scroll down I get this error: 'Cannot remove an observer... for the key path "status" from <AVPlayer 0x14ea3790> because it is not registered as an observer.'

Comment: Ok.  I included that because you are adding an observer to the player, so you should clear it.

Comment: it makes sense that I should remove it, I'm just not sure why I can't.  Let me know if u have any ideas please!

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of it this way. When you start loading your screen, you have a your `currentActiveIndex` as nil right? So what happens when that cell loads? Boom - the video shows up there.

And then of course, you go and actually set the `currentActiveIndex` when you tap on it and create a new cell, that's why you get this behavior. Here is what you should really do.

Have `currentActiveIndex` as a global variable or so. When you select a new value or so, just do a `self.tableview.reloadData()` which refreshes the whole UITableView or a `self.tableview.refreshSections("THE SECTION WITH THE VIDEOS")`. Decouple the `currentActiveIndex` logic from the UI Part.

Comment: hey this seems like a good example but im having trouble converting it to code.  would you mind showing an example?